# Paypal IPN Express checkout not working in simulator

Tags: paypal

I am using Paypal IPN

I have written a script that works fine with the Web Accept transaction type when used with the simulator.  I get the variables back and process them etc However when I switch the transaction type to express checkout it stops working.  Can anyone help me figure out why?

My code is in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is sort of old, but in case others land on this page with the same problem... If you're using the IPN Listener code from the official PayPal Developer site, you probably still have some code in there that's expecting specific form POST items, and that's the problem. Those items do not exist in the IPN Simulator's Express Checkout messages. Here's the problematic code:

```
   // assign posted variables to local variables
   $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
   $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
```

The Express Checkout form post will not have item_name nor item_number, but it will have item_name1 and item_number1. So, a good solution would be to take out all those lines of code, in that section, that specify form field names, and instead iterate through all the form fields.  In the loop, you can test for existence of expected items, if needed.  Or, if you just want to do something with the full set of form items, you could do that, like this:

```
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
       $strOutput .= $key . " = " . $value . "|";
    }
```

FYI... The problematic code was found here: 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/
...and here: 
https://gist.github.com/xcommerce-gists/3440401#file-completelistener-php